# Cypress doesn't like to share the value with multiple aliases

Tags: javascript, cypress, cypress-intercept

In my beforeEach I have

```
cy.intercept('GET', '**/api/v2/invoices**').as('getPaidInvoices');
```

I have some tests where I use getPaidInvoices with exactle same path. But then I have different test

```
cy.intercept('GET', '**/api/v2/invoices**').as('getInvoices');
cy.wait('@getInvoices').then((xhr) => {
expect(xhr.response.statusCode).to.equal(200);
```

Then I have cy with each loop for options in drop-down menu. By clicking on each option inside, I await request different for each option. The address is almost the same, except the last two ** will get different arguments.

**The problem** seems Cypress doesn't like to share the value of getPaidInvoices with GetInvoices. On the line with

```
cy.intercept('GET', '**/api/v2/invoices**').as('getInvoices');
```

it says "This request matched: cy.intercept() spy with alias @getPaidInvoices

Is there any workaround? I need "**/api/v2/invoices**" to be used my multiple aliases. Or is there option to do it without aliases?

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This part `'GET', '**/api/v2/invoices**'` is the "routeMatcher". When two intercepts use the same routeMatcher, the last one defined is *supposed* to be the one that handles the call.

However, from your description, it seems to be the other way round.

There's a couple of ways to handle it, the best IMO is to use a function and assign the alias within it

From [Aliasing individual requests](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Aliasing-individual-requests)

```js
cy.intercept('GET', '**/api/v2/invoices**', (req) => {

  // test the url string
  if (req.url.includes('paid')) {  // check the arguments
    req.alias = 'getPaidInvoices'
  } else {
    req.alias = 'getInvoices'
  }
})
```